# Change app language in phonegap, app language settings

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I want to change the application language internally (like English, French, German, etc.) in my app using Phonegap and jQuery Mobile.

Now I am trying globalization API. In this API we can only get the system language. So how do I change the language?

Here is the [link](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-globalization/blob/dev/doc/index.md) what I am trying right now.

Answer (score 1):

To change the application language, first of all your app must be localized

To localize the app with javascript, using [jquery globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize), [webL10n](https://github.com/fabi1cazenave/webL10n) or any other javascript localization library. Then you can use the language you get from globalization API or change it dinamically to display any language you want in your app.